# how to add 1 year in the value of the date object?

Tags: mysql, database, date, servlets

I am new to using date objects in servlets to store dates in the database. I have used this code to create a date object and store today's date in it. Now i need to add 1 year in this date and need to store in another date object please help me with this problem.

```
        java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
        String DATE_FORMAT = "MM-dd-yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        String strDateNew = sdf.format(now) ;
```

Comment: Using `Date` directly has been deprecated as far as I know, look into the `Calendar` class instead for future compatability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code after creating the new date object.

```
now.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
```